# My improved answer based on another's accepted answer for my own question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, accepted-answer, etiquette, self-answer

Yesterday, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270078/stretching-controls-to-fill-itemscontrol/1270813) in which I stated a primary requirement but also asked for an optional improvement.  The primary requirement was answered perfectly, and I upvoted it and accepted it.  Building on that answer, I was subsequently able to solve the optional improvement as well.  I'd like to share the improved solution but I'm not sure of the best way to do so.  I suspect I should either:

1. Add another answer to my own question explaining how I was able to enhance the accepted answer (but leave the existing accepted answer as is)
2. Add a comment to the existing accepted answer explaining the additions required to satisfy the optional improvement.

The problem with (2) is that I'd like to give code samples and comments are very limiting in that regard.

Obviously the person who answered the question deserves the "credit", but I also feel it benefits the community to have the additional information.  How should I handle this?

Comment: In my case, I'm rather new to this community and have nowhere near the rep necessary to edit the accepted answer.  I didn't specify that because I figured that this question would be more beneficial to the community if it provoked answers that would apply to either side of the answer edit threshold (or both).

Comment: +1 on your SO question - it's a well-written question that three people answered, but no one yet voted up.. /grumble

Comment: Thanks for the input all, I'm going to follow both mmyers' and RichieHindle's advice.  (And thanks John, I try to remedy that situation when I find it for others as well.  It, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be too uncommon but I assume it rights itself over time.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you haven't reached 2000 rep yet, then I think #1 is preferable.
If you have reached 2000 rep, then the best way would be to edit your improvements into the accepted answer (along with a note of explanation).

Answer (score 6):

Do both: Add the enhancements as a new answer, and add a comment to the accepted answer pointing people to the enhancements answer.

(I'm assuming you don't have enough rep to edit the accepted answer.)