# Indicate when a suggested edit is made on the accepted answer, or by the original asker

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, user-interface

When browsing suggested edits, I sometimes see significant content changes which I would normally reject. However, in many cases I think [it would be appropriate to accept such changes on the accepted answer, especially by the original asker of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/my-improved-answer-based-on-anothers-accepted-answer-for-my-own-question). Can the review page indicate when either of these is the case?

Comment: I usually just look at the question in cases where I'm wondering something like this. Often times, you'll see people leaving comments that explain or justify their suggested edits, too.

Answer (score 2):

With the new review queue for suggested edits is easier to understand when the edit was approved from the author of the post: The username is drawn using a different background, similarly to what done for questions, and any comment left from the OP.

[image: screenshot]

Now that suggested edits need to be approved/rejected from more than one user, when a suggested edit is approved from a single user (and the review page doesn't list the Community user as approver/rejecter), it means the user is a moderator, or the user is the author of the post for which the edit has been suggested. With the different background color, it is easier to know when the user was the post author.